# OSMNX and Shapely polygon cut

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, osmnx

I wanted to spilt the polygon into a numbered grid consisting of many small squares/shapes but the result is a polygon split into four sections instead is there anything wrong with the code I have been trying to solve this for hours but not sure what to do:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import geopandas as gpd
 import osmnx as ox
 from descartes import PolygonPatch
 from shapely.geometry import Polygon
 city=ox.geocode_to_gdf("Paris,France")

 geometry = city['geometry'].iloc[0]
 geometry_split = 
 ox.utils_geo._quadrat_cut_geometry(geometry, 
 quadrat_width = 750)

 polylist = [p for p in geometry_split]

 west, south, east, north = city.unary_union.bounds
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))
 for polygon, n in zip(geometry_split, 
 np.arange(len(polylist))):
 p = polygon.representative_point().coords[:][0]
 patch = 
 PolygonPatch(polygon,ec='#100000',alpha=0.5, 
 zorder=2)
 ax.add_patch(patch)
 plt.annotate(text=n, xy=p, 
 horizontalalignment='center', size=15)
 ax.set_xlim(west, east)
 ax.set_ylim(south, north)
 ax.axis('off')
 plt.show()
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

Comment: How many squares do you want? What should their widths be? In what units?

Comment: I want the polygon to be divided into a grid consisting of quadratic cells where the quadrat width is 750 metres.

Comment: You'll need to project your GeoDataFrame to a meter projection if you want to work in meters.

Comment: I have watched your video in skillshare about urban modelling and attempting practising doing a similar grid to yours but mine turns out like instead. I have tried figuring out what I did different for hours but don't know what to do. Please would you let me know I would really appreciate. :)

Comment: I'm not clear on what info you need. GeoDataFrame projection is detailed in the OSMnx documentation and demonstrated in its usage examples repo. Beyond that, what further info are you looking for?

Comment: For reference, documentation on the `project_gdf` function: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.projection.project_gdf